# Spring Validator throws NotReadablePropertyException on POST

Tags: spring, spring-validator

I am trying to validate an object and return a meaningful response message using the Spring Validator.

I want it to check for a condition that a given `String` can only be of 5 certain values.

What's instead happening is that I am getting an `NotReadablePropertyException` thrown and returning basically nothing..

What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
public void validate(Object obj, Errors error) {
    Jobs job = (Jobs) obj;
    String recurrence = job.getRecurrence();

    if(!recurrence.equals(RecurrenceStatus.TEST) 
            && !recurrence.equals(RecurrenceStatus.DAILY) && !recurrence.equals(RecurrenceStatus.FREQUENTLY) 
            && !recurrence.equals(RecurrenceStatus.WEEKLY) && !recurrence.equals(RecurrenceStatus.MONTHLY)){

        error.rejectValue("RECURRENCE STATUS", "422", "The recurrence status must be one of these: " + RecurrenceStatus.ALLSTATUS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the signature of `rejectValue(java.lang.String field, java.lang.String errorCode, java.lang.String defaultMessage)`  you can see that the first parameter is  `field`. It refers to a field in your `Jobs` class.

I don’t think that your current value for `field` = "RECURRENCE STATUS" does that!

You should change it to the referenceing field of your Jobs class.

Check out the Spring Errors [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: yep... I changed it to `recurrence` and now it's working!